# Multiple UrlSessionTask in a loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I'm new to iOS and the project I worked on require parsing json into local database.

The situation is that I have to loop through multiple http requests first and generate a array of NSDictionary. I have a method to insert object using Dictionary.

```
for (NSNumber *cd_id in self.deviceIDList) {
    NSURL *getDeviceUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.abc.com/v2/devices/%@/?session_key=123",cd_id]];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *deviceTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:getDeviceUrl completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        [self processDeviceData:data];
    }];
    [deviceTask resume];
}
```

---

```
- (void)processDeviceData:(NSData *)data{
    NSError *JSONError = nil;
    NSDictionary *deviceDetail = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                 options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                                                   error:&JSONError];
    [self.deviceDetailList addObject:deviceDetail];
    if (JSONError) {
        NSLog(@"json data = %@", deviceDetail);
    }
}
```

The processDeviceData method simply create dictionaries from json and put them into an array. However, I failed to create the **deviceDetailList** array.

Is this the proper way to do it?

Comment: So the problem is simply creating an array before you start?

Comment: You also need to deal with the concurrent access to the array - NSMutableArray is not thread safe

Comment: @Wain Could you explain it in detail?

Answer (score 0):

So, you already have a property `deviceDetailList`, which should be an `NSMutableArray`. In your `init` method on this class you should be creating an empty array instance:

```
self.deviceDetailList = [NSMutableArray array];
```

And then in the task completion block you should use GCD to switch back to the main thread to update your array:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [self processDeviceData:data];

    // probably trigger a UI update here...
});
```